# Dropdown Bootstrap does not open

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I'm currently learning Vuejs, bootstrap, bootstrap-vue-3, and Vue Router. But somehow the dropdown does not open.

Here is my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-66s6dv?

The bootstrap source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *bootstrap source* your are working with (based on your link), is from `Bootstrap 4.4` and it's slightly, but different to `Bootstrap 5`.

A version of `Bootstrap 4` is not compatible to `Vuejs 3`.

So I would recommend to use the latest `Bootstrap 4.6` with `Vuejs 2` - than you can use `BootstrapVue 2.21.2`.

Here is a link to show how you am able to run it togehter which the different version:
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs